# Update Code In Production Mode

Tags: magento2

Recently I made my Magento 2.3.1 website live and set mode as "production". Now If I try to run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` then it starts showing error

`An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.`

In order to protect this I need to set `Maintenance mode` and website goes offline. Is it anyway by which we can run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and  website will not show error.

Same thing happens during `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. It distorted the page layout.

Comment: Yes it is in production mode `Current application mode: production. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)
`

Comment: ok wait am adding my ans! check it now

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse there is.

First you just make it production skipping compilation.

> php magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation

Then, run

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Voila, error will be shown. Try it.

Comment: My webiste is already in production mode and if run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` then it shows errors

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old error that has not yet fixed by magento but in order to fix this you can follow these steps-

add the expected library from require-dev to require, giving a require setting in `PhpCsFixerReview.php`

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.5",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1"
},
```

hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I am unable to find any file with name PhpCsFixerReview.php

Comment: me to cant find the file in directory

Comment: actually its a tool that automatically fixes all coding errors i think you are unaware of that